# Filter table results based on multiple dropdown selections

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have 2 HTML dropdowns, name and date. Selecting a name, will filter the date dropdowns for only the dates that correspond with that name. After each selection, results are filtered and displayed in a table.

For example, if I select `Name A`, the table will display all results for `Name A`. Then if I select `Date A` afterwards, the table will display all results for `Date A`. However, I want it to filter so that if a name is chosen first and then a date, that it will filter both in the table results.

Like this:
If `Name A` is selected, then `Date A` is selected, the table will display all results for `Name A` AND `Date A`.

Currently, I am only storing the current selection of the dropdown with the variable `$q`. How can I do this so that it will be able to filter results on multiple selections?

HTML Dropdowns:

```
<form name="testForm" action="">
    <select id="collector" onchange="showUser(this.value)">             
        <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Collector Name</option>
        <?php foreach($collect->fetchAll() as $name) { ?>
            <option class="choice" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($name['Collector Name']);?>"><?php echo $name['Collector Name'];?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>


    <select id="date" onchange="showUser(this.value)">              
        <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Bill Date</option>
        <?php foreach($bill_date->fetchAll() as $date) { ?>
            <option class="choice" value="<?php echo $date['Date'];?>"><?php echo $date['Date'];?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
</form>
```

JavaScript in `head` tag that is called with onchange in select tag and JavaScript outside function in onchange that filters the date dropdown after a name selection has been made:

```
function showUser(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;

            var newTableObject = document.getElementById('billing_table');
            sorttable.makeSortable(newTableObject);

        }
    }

        xmlhttp.open("GET","dropdown-display.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();

        document.getElementById('billing_table').style.display = 'none';

}
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#collector").change(function(e){
        $.post('index-ajax.php',{filter:'Name',by:$(this).val()},function(data){
            $("#date .choice").hide();
            $.each(data, function(key,row) {
       //       $("#date option[value='"+ row.item +"']").show();
                $("#date option").filter(function(i){
                    return $(this).attr("value").indexOf( row.item ) != -1;
                }).show();
            });
        },"JSON");
  });
});
```

And then I get the value of the most recently selected dropdown item in `dropdown-display.php` in `$q` which I use in my queries to filter the table results:

```
$q = ($_GET['q']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you'd like to do, the user can select a date but not a name (you're setting it with all the values from your php). But you don't want to do anything with the date unless a name is selected? Then why set it with values to begin with? When a user changes the name the dates are set are they not?

Anyway; when a user changes either of the select items it will call showUser with the following code (not send date parameter if it's empty):

You have to removing `onchange="showUser(this.value)"` from the html.

```
function showUser(collector,date) {
  $('#billing_table').hide();
  if (collector == "") {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
      return;
  } else { 
    $.ajax(
      "dropdown-display.php"
      ,{
        data:{
          q:collector
          ,data:date||undefined//will not send dae if date is "" or falsy
        }
      }
    ).then(
      function(responseText){
        $("#txtHint").html(responseText);
        sorttable.makeSortable($('#billing_table')[0]);
      }
      ,function(error){
        console.warn("something went wrong:",error);
        debugger;//this will pause if you have dev tools open (press F12)
      }
    )

  }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#collector, #date").change(function(e){
    showUser(
      $("#collector").val()
      ,$("#date").val()
    );
  });
  //...other code
});
```

Comment: Hey, I was wondering if you could help me out with something that is relatable to this problem I had since you had helped me out with this. Every time I save a row, I want the table to filter the results again so the user can see the most up to date results and not still see the rows they just edited and saved. I need a query to basically re-run whenever the ajax is complete. This used to be working when i had the onchange event but now that i do not have it, i havent been able to find a solution to fix this problem...i have a post about it here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47265342/running-sql-query-after-ajax-completes/47266435#47266435